# Determining the maximum number of linearly independent rows and columns for a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Here's the specific question:

> For the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&2 & 0 & 3\\ 1 & 2& 3 & 3 \\ 1  & 0 &
> 1 & 1 \\1 & 1 & 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$$ determine the maximum number of
>   linearly independent rows and the maximum number of linearly
>   independent columns.

I know that we say that rows/columns $\mathbf{x_1},\mathbf{x_2},\ldots\mathbf{x_p}$ are called **linearly independent** if the only scalars $\lambda_1, \ldots,\lambda_p$ which are such that $$\lambda_1\mathbf{x_1}+\lambda_2\mathbf{x_2}+\ldots+\lambda_n\mathbf{x_p}=\mathbf{0}$$ are $\lambda_1=\lambda_2=\ldots=\lambda_p=0$.

Okay, but that leaves me 11 possible sets of columns and rows to consider. First let us consider the columns $\mathbf{x_1},\mathbf{x_2},\mathbf{x_3}, \mathbf{x_4}$. Suppose that we have $\lambda_1\mathbf{x_1}+\lambda_2\mathbf{x_2}+\lambda_3\mathbf{x_3}+\lambda_4\mathbf{x_4}=\mathbf{0}$ for some scalars $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4$. Then

$$\lambda_1\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} + \lambda_2\begin{bmatrix}2\\2\\0\\3\end{bmatrix}  + \lambda_3\begin{bmatrix}0\\3\\1\\1\end{bmatrix} + \lambda_4\begin{bmatrix}3\\3\\1\\2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

and consequently
$$\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 + 3\lambda_4 &=& 0 \\
\lambda_1 + 2\lambda_2 + 3\lambda_3 + 3\lambda_4 &=& 0 \\
\lambda_1 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 &=& 0 \\
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + 2\lambda_4 &=& 0
\end{eqnarray}$$

and clearly $\lambda_1 = 1 , \lambda_2 = 1 , \lambda_3 = 0 , \lambda_4 =-1$ is a solution. Thus, columns $\mathbf{x_1},\mathbf{x_2},\mathbf{x_3}, \mathbf{x_4}$ are not linearly independent.

**Do I need to repeat this for every possible group of columns and rows?** But then if we consider $3$ columns, we'll get a homogeneous system of $4$ equations with $3$ unknowns. How do I tackle this problem?

This is a question from [Basic Linear Algebra - Blyth, Robertson](https://www.springer.com/in/book/9781852336622). **The authors have defined row reduced matrices and hermite matrices in the quest of a systematic method of tackling system of linear equations. *Rank of matrices, Vector Spaces, Linear Mappings, Determinants are yet to be discussed.***

Comment: With refernce to $Ax=0$, we don't need to solve for every possible group of columns. Indeed once we have the solution $x$ we oanly need to consider the dimension of the subspace (defined N(A)) of that solution. If $N(A)=0$ the columns are linearly independent, if $N(A)=1$ we have $n-1$ linearly independent columns, and so on. To select a Group of linearly independent columns the best way is by RREF looking at the pivots.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in order to determine the number of linearly independent colums we need to solve the homogeneous system

$$Ax=0$$

and find the dimension of the null space of $A.$ Notably if $x=0$ is the unique solution, $\dim(N(A))=0$ and all the $n$ columns are linearly independent. Otherwise, and more in general, if $\dim(N(A))=d$, the number of linearly independent colums is $n-d$.

For the rows we need to solve

$$A^Tx=0$$

and we'll find that $\dim(N(A))=\dim(N(A^T));$ that is, the **maximum number of linearly independent rows is equal to the maximum number of linearly independent columns**.

That's true for any matrix and that number is defined as the **rank of A**.